# ASP.NET Core and TFS2015 API

Tags: asp.net-core, tfs-2015

I have a WebAPI that retrieves information from TFS 2015 using its API and is consumed by a client to monitor build statuses.

I decided I would like to upgrade this to use the new ASP.NET Core framework however I cannot get past a compatibility problem; when I install the TFS Api components via NuGet I get multiple dependency issues. (I should say that I am not trying amend the WebAPI project but writing a new ASP.Net Core project that I will point the client at when finished).

> error: Package Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient 15.112.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient 15.112.1 supports:
>   error:   - native (native,Version=v0.0)
>   error:   - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
>   error: Package System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 4.0.2.206221351 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 4.0.2.206221351 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
>   error: Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.2 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.2 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
>   error: Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client 15.112.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client 15.112.1 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
>   error: Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.InteractiveClient 15.112.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.InteractiveClient 15.112.1 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
>   error: Package Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client 15.112.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client 15.112.1 supports: net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
>   error: One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.

It seems that the TFS libraries cannot be used with .NET Core 1.0.1.

I am using VS2015.

As I am new to using the new Core framework can anyone enlighten me on what I am doing wrong, or indeed whether this is in fact possible at all.

**EDIT**

Relates to suggestion by Tingting0929-MSFT (below) - this is the state of affairs after suggested changes:-

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are right, the package does not run on .NET Core, so you *could* retarget your application to run on the full .NET framework. However, looking at the dependencies there, it depends on `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core`. I would strongly suggest you *not* to mix the older ASP.NET WebAPI with ASP.NET Core. So the answer is probably that you simply cannot use this package with ASP.NET Core. Consider talking to TFS directly using its REST API.

Answer (score 1):

This package doesn't not support with asp.net core project directly in VS 2015 for ASP.NET Core project.

But as a workaround, you could use VS 2017 to install the dependency packages for you ASP.NET Core project.

First add the following to your *.csproj file.

```
<PropertyGroup>  
    <PackageTargetFallback>portable-net451+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then look at the picture below, the `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient` package is depended on these packages listed below. You could install these packages like `Microsoft.VisualStudio.services.client` and the `Microsoft.TeamFoundationSever.Client` packages individually for your donet core project.

[image]

Comment: I tried these suggestions - unfortunately I think this is not going to be something that is possible. I have edited my question to include the errors after the changes

Comment: @EzaBlade Sorry that I didn't notice that you're using VS 2015 at the beginning. I have updated my reply. The method I posted above works for ASP.NET Core project which is created in VS 2017. In VS 2015, the packages and it's dependency packages are not support to install.

Comment: @EzaBlade Did you still have questions about it? Did you solve it in VS 2017?

Comment: I abandoned my attempts as we are not yet using VS 2017. Thanks for suggestions and attempts to help.